# Not receiving e-mail notifications

Tags: support, stack-overflow, email

I'm not receiving my notifying e-mails properly from Stack Overflow. What should I do?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What mail are you expecting, and why?

Comment: whenever i get an answer for the question in stackoverflow,i am not getting notification mail to mail address.

Answer (score 1):

Is your email address set? (we don't require email)

Did you ensure that you do not have opt out of email set in your user preferences?

Our email notifications are sent out daily so it may take a while.

Comment: for this question,i got a notification mail that you answered. but when ever i have a answer in stackoverflow i am not get such email.